# What's the history of the English letter "Y" as a "sometimes vowel"?

Tags: history, pronunciation-vs-spelling, vowels, rules, vowel-length

Wondering when and why historically the Anglo-Saxon letter "Y" became a (part-time) vowel substitute for the letter "I", leading to "gymnasium" instead of "gimnasium" or "cyanide" instead of "cianide" etc.

Comment: 'Y' is a full vowel in 'gymnasium' and 'cyanide' but a semivowel in 'yellow'.

Comment: Neither the Angles nor the Saxons nor even the Jutes, let alone the English, invented [the letter Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y). It comes to us from Greek by way of Latin, not from the [fuþorc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo-Saxon_runes).

Comment: First tell us about the history of the classification "vowel".

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that *Y* has always been used as a vowel in English.

For example, [hyð](http://www.bosworthtoller.com/020404). The OED has a citation from Corpus Glossary (c736):

> *Deconfugione*, *statione*, hyðae.

And another from Metres of Boethius (1000):

> Þæt is sio an hyð.